# Does reflection group induce group structure on $\mathbb{R}P^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, euclidean-geometry, projective-space, reflection

Let $\text{Ref}_a: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a reflection through the hyperplane defined by $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$. It seems obvious to me that $\text{Ref}_a\circ \text{Ref}_b=\text{Ref}_c$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$ (since for every two points $x,y \in S^n$ we find a hyperplane $H$, s.t. $d(H,x)=d(H,y)$). This seems a bit naive, but is there an associative multiplication $\#$ on $\mathbb{R}P^n$, s.t. $\text{Ref}_a\circ \text{Ref}_b=\text{Ref}_{a\#b}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A reflection through a hyperplane has determinant $-1$. Hence the composition of two such reflections has determinant $1$, therefore it is not a reflection through a hyperplane. So what may seem obvious is in fact false.

With respect to composition, the reflections through hyperplanes generate the [unitary group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_group). It consists of all reflections and rotations of $\Bbb{R}^n$. Its action on $\Bbb{R}^n$ descends to an action on $\Bbb{R}P^n$, leading to the [projective unitary group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_unitary_group). It is in general much larger than $\Bbb{R}P^n$ itself, which makes it unlikely to give rise to any kind of multiplication on $\Bbb{R}P^n$ (canonically).

Comment: Thx! My (really embarassing) mistake was that clearly I find a $c$, s.t. $Ref_aRef_b(v)=Ref_c(v)$, but of course $c$ depends on $v$..

Comment: Your intuition wasn't far off though, you just need to include rotations to actually get a group with respect to composition. Alternatively you could consider the operation $a\#b=c$ where $c$ is defined by the identity
$$\text{Ref}_a\circ \text{Ref}_b=-\text{Ref}_c,$$
which *does* define a unique reflection for every pair of reflections. It doesn't give you a group structure on $\Bbb{R}^n$, but it is an interesting operator nonetheless.

Comment: This is nice, after all its a semigroup structure on $RP^n$... in your answer you mean the orthogonal group $O(n)$, since we are in $R^n$, right?

Comment: You're absolutely right, it should be the orthogonal group $O(n)$. I've never understood why there is different notation for $\Bbb{R}$ and $\Bbb{C}$, but maybe I haven't worked with them enough to understand the difference.